# How to aggregate index values in pivot table function in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I'm new at Python and I would appreciate your help.

I created a pivot table using the pivot_table function:
`df2=df[["group_name"," revenue ","RPM"]]`
`df3=df2.pivot_table(index="RPM",columns="group_name",aggfunc="count")`

The RPM index contains values from 0 to 15 - for instance - 0.03,0.54,0.15,5.62,13,45
I would like to group the index values to a specific interval, so it will be like 0-1,1-2...

```
revenue
group_name  A   B
RPM     
0.12    1.0 NaN
0.13    1.0 NaN
0.14    NaN 1.0
0.15    1.0 NaN
0.17    1.0 2.0
... ... ...
10.09   NaN 1.0
10.15   NaN 1.0
10.22   NaN 1.0
11.76   NaN 1.0
14.04   NaN 1.0
```

Is it possible to do this in Python?

Thanks!

Comment: please show and example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say your data frame is something like this:

```
np.random.seed(111)
df = pd.DataFrame({"group_name":np.random.randint(0,3,100),
                  "revenue":np.random.uniform(0,10,100),
                  "RPM":np.random.uniform(0,20,100)})
```

You can define the boundaries to cut your column:

```
br = np.arange(21)
```

Then when you pivot, you provide the discretized column instead of the actual column as index:

```
df.pivot_table(index=pd.cut(df.RPM,br),columns="group_name",values="revenue",aggfunc="count")

group_name  0   1   2
RPM         
(0, 1]      NaN 3.0 2.0
(1, 2]      NaN NaN 3.0
(2, 3]      2.0 NaN 1.0
(3, 4]      5.0 1.0 1.0
(4, 5]      3.0 3.0 5.0
(5, 6]      2.0 NaN NaN
(6, 7]      2.0 1.0 1.0
(7, 8]      2.0 1.0 1.0
(8, 9]      2.0 5.0 1.0
(9, 10]     2.0 4.0 2.0
(10, 11]    1.0 2.0 3.0
(11, 12]    5.0 3.0 NaN
(12, 13]    2.0 2.0 NaN
(13, 14]    1.0 NaN NaN
(14, 15]    NaN 1.0 1.0
(15, 16]    1.0 3.0 2.0
(16, 17]    1.0 1.0 3.0
(17, 18]    3.0 NaN 1.0
(18, 19]    2.0 2.0 2.0
(19, 20]    2.0 1.0 NaN
```